# Is it OK that my AC is making squeaking and rattling noises?

Tags: repair, hvac

Just want to get some initial thoughts before the repairman comes. I have a 3 year old 2.5 ton Goodman AC unit. I set the temperature to 74°F last night (AC) and woke up to a nice and chilly house. An odd noise was coming from the outside unit — almost a high pitched squeak followed by a rattle and then the unit kicks off. Several seconds later, the unit kicks on and the pattern of squeak, rattle, shut off continues. The fan is not obstructed, and spins cleanly.

It's still blowing cold air in the house and the coils appear fine and not frozen. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

All mechanical parts wear down in time.  The bearings on your fan might be going, or it could just need some lubrication.  Before you call the repair guy, try to remove the unit's outer housing and add some type of Teflon based lubricant to any friction areas of moving parts.

Comment: Look in the unit's manual to see what type of lubricants it recommends, and where.

Comment: Agreed, that is best practice.  In general white lithium can be used when that information isn't available.